# What are the corresponding easter eggs for John Williams' 52 Oscar Nominations?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker, music, easter-egg, john-williams

Not only does legendary composer John Williams have a cameo in *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*, but director J.J. Abrams states that every single item in that scene has been very purposefully chosen to represent the 52 academy award nominated film scores by the maestro.

This [behind-the-scenes video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGc47-ncN70) touches on a few of them but I and many others would like to know what are the corresponding items for John Williams' 52 Oscar Nominations?

---

<sup>visuals (screenshots, timestamps, etc.) are preferred but not required</sup>

Comment: There's also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf_4b2mIVD8)

Comment: Here's a link to his Academy Award [list of nominations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_awards_and_nominations_received_by_John_Williams#Academy_Awards), which might help ID the objects.

Answer (score 2):

This is an incomplete answer but nonethless I will update as I will find more

The air canisters as seen in Jaws

[image]

The iconic hook from Hook

[image]

Star Wars style dog tags from Saving Private Ryan

[image]

A small scale model of E.T.'s ship from E.T.

[image]

The time turner from Harry Potter

[image]

Wands from Harry Potter

[image]

Iron from Home Alone

[image]

Fiddle and Bow from Fiddler on the Roof

[image]

Open reel tape deck from Nixon

[image]

Catch me if you can -

[image]

Iconic whip from Indiana Jones

[image]

Sankara stones from Indiana Jones

[image]

The book from The Book Thief

[image]

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf_4b2mIVD8), [source 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGc47-ncN70), [Source 3](https://thedirect.com/article/the-rise-of-skywalker-documentary-reveals-easter-egg-props)

Comment: What is the source of the pictures with annotations?